# Relational flat-file database

Tags: relational-database, flat-file

For a small application, need to use a flat file database with relational capabilities (2 or 3 tables).

Couple questions regarding this schema:

1. Does such databases exist?
2. Any performance hits with large datasets? (say, 10k-20k entries)

The reason I want to go with a flat-file database is so the whole thing(root directory) can be copied and pasted, and not have to worry about exporting the database, installing & configuring a database in another system, etc.

thanks.

Comment: You didn't specify language... In Java, I'd use H2SQL,, and save a lot of time not worrying about special issues. It can be embedded into the app itself, so it is portable that way.

Comment: How about [SQLLite](http://www.sqlite.org)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org).

It is easy to use, portable, no configuration and has great performance (10k / 20k is nothing)